# align image in paragraph html css

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've tried several properties like 'vertical-align' but I cant align the image with center of paragraph

```
HTML:
<p><img id="imgPhone" src="phone.png">00244 913 513 199</p>

CSS:
img {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zYeA/6/)

Comment: You won't be able to use `vertical-align` unless the img is **outside** the paragraph.

Comment: normally floated elements should not be aligned, it's hard to align them because they are pulled out of the inline document flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can simple add:

```
p {
        line-height: 50px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` doesn't work with `floats`.
Try this:

```
p,
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: img has `display:inline-block` by default, so just remove the `float:left` and add `vertical-align:middle`, however maybe the OP still wants to keep using `float`

Comment: wish to vote up your answer, but it requires 15 reputation.

thank you!

Comment: Thats's oke, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

you should wrap both elements in a div and use `line-height`. also an `img` tag inside a `p` tag is not exactly a good idea

http://jsfiddle.net/omegaiori/6zYeA/7/

Comment: is not good idea for markup purpose right?

wish to vote up your answer, but it requires 15 reputation.

thank you!